# How to override onBackPressed in another class with activity parameter?

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void launch(Activity activity, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        UpdateHelper.getInstance().init(activity);

        injectResource(activity);

        initSDKLayout(activity);

    ｝
｝
```

Above is the code I have. Can I use activity in this class to override activity method `onBackPressed()`？ I am asking this because I can't use activity class directly.

Comment: In your activity, when onBackPressed is called you could do `launcher.onBackPressed()`. In that way you can change its behaviour with composition

Comment: Thanks in advance.  The class luncher is not an activity, this is an SDK project and luncher is for load the activity of game project,so I can't override onBackPressed. But I need to do something when back button pressed.  So, do u have some idea?